# Type Mismatch Error on Empty Cells?

Tags: vba, excel

With the following code displayed below, I seem to be getting `Type Mismatch` errors as soon as it hits empty cells. Usually, the max range is A1:MZ1.
The code splits a cell with 4 lines of text into 4 rows.

```
Dim SplitText
Dim myRange As Range, k As Range

Set myRange = Sheet2.Range("A1:LN1")

For Each k In myRange
    SplitText = Split(k, vbLf)
    k.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1) = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
Next
```

Initially, I thought this might have been due to a transpose length limit, but that doesn't appear to be the case after all.
I tried adding an If Statement, but that unfortunately didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Test the value of `k` before trying to split it.

Comment: @braX Thanks for your response. The splitting process itself works, as long as the range doesn't include any empty cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you making your life difficult... Simply check for `vbLf` and split by it if it is there:

```
For Each k In myRange
    If InStr(1, k, vbLf) Then
        SplitText = Split(k, vbLf)
        k.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1) = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @Viyata Probably because I am new to this :) Anyway, I ran your suggestion and looks like it works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Francis - thumbs up for the correct usage of `.Resize` then :)

Comment: @Viyata Hehe, thanks! Have a great upcoming weekend!

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
SplitText = Split(k & vbLf, vbLf)
```

A truly blank cell is empty but a cell containing a line feed has something that Split can work with.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution works for me as well. I tried out Viyata's approach first, so went with that. Nonetheless, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way should be to check if the `k` is empty or not

```
If Not IsEmpty(k) Then
    SplitText = Split(k, vbLf)
    k.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1) = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I ran it but get an error `Object variable or With variable not set` on the line `SplitText = Split(k, vbLf)`. I did however, get a solution that works from Viyata. Cheers!

Comment: Of course you need to place this inside your `For` loop